# How to plot 3D in octave

Tags: plot, octave

Hi I'm starting to use Octave and need help on how to plot x²+y² = 1.
I know that the figure is a cylinder.
I tried:

`x= -10:0.1:10;
 y = -10:0.1:10;
 t = x²+y²;`

but it won't work.

Comment: Squaring is `x.^2` in Octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular situation, you can just use the `cylinder` function.

`cylinder([a,b])`

will plot a cylinder whose radius at `z==0` will be equal to `a`, and will vary continuously and smoothly until its radius at `z==1` reaches `b`. In you case, you need to set `a` and `b` to `1`, which is what happens by default when you call `cylinder()`.

Now this will plot the cylinder with only `z` values in `[0,1]`. If you want to customize that range, you can just get the output from the function like this:

```
[xx yy zz]=cylinder([1,1]);
```

And now you can use this to obtain the plot that you want. For example,

```
surf(xx,yy,zz.*10);hold on; surf(xx,yy,-zz.*10);
```

will produce this:

[image]

Comment: It works, Thanks. But, why after the hold on; surf has -zz? it plots some kind of function in the back of the cylinder, i fixed it changing the "-" with a "," and plots the sme cylinder.

Comment: @Herondealejandria the components of `zz`are all in the interval `[0,1]`, so I assumed that `surf(xx,yy,-zz*some_val)` would plot the cylinder with  `z` values between `[-some_val, 0]`. It seems to work for me and I don' t see any artifacts, but maybe this doesn't always hold. Anyway, the point of that part was just to say that you are not limited to the plot that `cylinder` makes and that you can take its output and do whatever you want with it.